# Why does my image convert to a tensor with only ones?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transform, tensor

I am using the GTZAN dataset (containing 1000 songs with 10 genres) to make a music genre classification project.
I tried to convert a dataset of images, which are spectrograms of the songs, into tensors but it only returns a tensor of ones.
This is how I tried to do it:

```
transform = T.Compose([
T.Resize(image_size),
T.ToTensor()
])

data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root = root, transform = transform)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset,
                          batch_size=batch_size,
                          shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset,
                         batch_size*2)

dataiter = iter(train_loader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
```

When I return images it gives a tensor of pure ones, e.g.

```
images[1]

tensor([[[1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Do you get the same output with a different normalize variable like `Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @SatyaPrakashDash I tried and it now shows a tensor with equal values. Like this: `images[2]
tensor([[2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286,  ..., 2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286],
        [2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286,  ..., 2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286],
        [2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286,  ..., 2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286],
        ...,
        [2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286,  ..., 2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286],
        [2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286,  ..., 2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286],
        [2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286,  ..., 2.4286, 2.4286, 2.4286]])`

Comment: @ellhe-blaster I added some more information, please let me know if there is anything else I should add.

Comment: It’s probably due to a normalization issue. Try (I) to apply ToTensor after after Normalize and (II) to divide/multiply the values by 255 before normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is all ones? Try to compute maximum/minimum/mean.
If that's the case, maybe you are reading the files assuming the wrong format.
This notebook could be of help https://www.kaggle.com/code/mireiaboneta/cnnmodel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).